# Launching iOS App in UI Testing Mode from Windows 10

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, uitest, launching

It is obvious that we can run iOS App (.ipa, .app) in UITest mode from MacOSX using Xcode or Xcode command line tools.

But I saw some test-automation tools, who can launch App in UITesting mode (Appium Studio, QUAmotion, Ranorex, ..etc) from Windows 10. They are even giving back elements. (which is possible only in UITestMode)

As per my knowledge, UI Testing mode is only supported on MacOSX with Xcode because Xcode has a testManager which it uses to manage the Testcases while running. As for iOS Device attached to windows. LibiMobileDevice with the help of itunes gives functionalities like installing, running, uninstalling etc.

Can any one explain or help me with some library (paid or free )that can help me in Launching iOS app with UI Testing mode on iOS Device from Windows 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

I work for Quamotion, one of the companies that you mentioned. You are right, we can run iOS appliations in UI Test mode on Windows and Linux, just like other vendors such as Ranorex.

If you're still interested, I'd be happy to help you getting started with launching iOS applications in UI testing mode on a real, physical iOS device in Windows 10.

The best way for you to get started would probably to [download the latest version of Quamotion](http://docs.quamotion.mobi/en/latest/getting-started/getting-started-windows.html), [request a 2-week trial license](http://quamotion.mobi/Mwc/License) and start one of the tutorials.

For example, we publish a [hands-on-lab](http://docs.quamotion.mobi/en/latest/hands-on-lab/acquaint/acquaint.html) which shows you, step by step, how you can automate the Acquaint iOS application on a real iPhone from a Windows PC.

Comment: To be fair if choosing a paid version of a product I'd go with Ranorex just because it's an all around tool with very good community and support from the staff. Though it being an all around tool I have still not met a competitive framework/out-of-the-box software that has come close to the desired functionality that Ranorex has given. Not related to Ranorex myself - just giving my 2 cents worth. Experience with it almost 5 years and more in the field.

Comment: 2023 update: the https://github.com/quamotion/Quamotion.WebDriver repo has no activity since 2019, and the http://docs.quamotion.mobi/ URL redirected to something called Eggplant... https://www.keysight.com/us/en/contact/eggplant/product-tour.html

Answer (score 0):

The are a few ways Ranorex mobile automation can enable a Windows machine to control an attached iOS device. The main way's setup is fairly involved. Managing the iPhones and iPads is like grooming pets. (As opposed to herding cattle, to mix a DevOps metaphor.) Requirements include.

1. the USB-connected mobile iOS device "trusts" the Windows PC
2. iTunes installed and recognizes the iOS device
3. The mobile app `.IPA` was compiled with Ranorex-specific libraries
4. the iOS device's unique USB address is in a signed `.mobileprovision` file
5. a "Ranorex Service App" is installed on the target iOS device, through which the instrumented build is installed and executed

I have not yet tried to connect Ranorex mobile automation with SauceLabs or BrowserStack or any other WebDriver-based protocol such as Appium. Support for such is mentioned in Ranorex web site pages (links below.) But it is unclear to me if that only applies to mobile-web.  I don't know if it is possible to do cloud testing of native iOS apps compiled in Objective-C or Swift.

- https://www.ranorex.com/integrations/
- https://www.ranorex.com/mobile-automation-testing/
- https://www.ranorex.com/mobile-automation-testing/ios-iphone-ipad-testing-automation/